# npm 3.5.4: EBUNDLEOVERRIDE during update causes npmlog error

Tags: node.js, npm

Upgraded to Node 5.4.0 via 'brew upgrade,' and then ran 'npm update -g,' which upgraded to npm 3.5.4. npm update finished with warnings:

```
/usr/local/lib
└── npm@3.5.4

npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > init-package-json with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > node-gyp with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > npm-install-checks with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > npmlog with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > read-package-json with new installed version
```

Running 'npm update -g' (or any other npm command) now throws npmlog errors:

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:20:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:76:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

It's not clear to me why the override is happening, or how to point npm to the logs again. Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (but I didn't upgrade node, just ran the global update). Found this googling for the error message and `Replacing bundled npm > npmlog with new installed version`. [Only answer I can find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) is to completely uninstall and reinstall npm. What a pain.

Comment: Discussion with the npm devs seems to indicate that the issue has to do with the prior version of npm (3.3.12 with a fresh Homebrew install, or 3.4.x, but apparently not a problem with 3.5.x updating to 3.5.4). Complete uninstall will only work until the next time you 'npm update -g,' and npm is updated to latest. Main fix will be when Homebrew version of node updates its npm to 3.5.x I believe/hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `brew reinstall node` is the least-destructive way to resolve this. Will install `node 3.3.12` while leaving everything else in place:

```
$ brew reinstall node
==> Reinstalling node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-5.4.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-5.4.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-5.4.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Please note by default only English locale support is provided. If you need
full locale support you should:
  `brew reinstall node --with-full-icu`

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.1: 2,827 files, 34.2M

$ npm outdated --global
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
npm       3.3.12   3.5.4   3.5.3
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - this is a great temporary fix, but as long as npm is managing itself, running 'npm update -g' will reintroduce the problem. I suppose one could avoid updating globally until the node package has npm 3.5.x, but that could take a while. I may need to simply leave Homebrew behind on this one and install node/npm directly at the current version (with or without a version manager). That would skip over the upgrade from 3..3.12 and presumably resolve the issue.

Comment: @Dusty Looks like homebrew is now serving `node 5.4.1_1` which comes with `npm 3.5.3`. I was able to then `npm update -g` to `npm 3.5.4` which seems to have worked.

Comment: Outstanding - this works for me as well. Thanks for taking the time to follow up!

Comment: I'm having this issue when trying to deploy our app to a Heroku instance that does not have brew installed.  Is the guidance to try to install brew on the Heroku dyno, or does anyone know of an alternate fix?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I [completely reinstalled npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) which seemed to be the only solution I could find for this error. It fixed it for me.

Comment: Complete uninstall followed by 'brew install node' yields npm v. 3.3.12. This version works. Subsequently running 'npm update -g' yields npm v. 3.5.4, with the same EBUNDLEOVERRIDE and errors I described. The problem seems to be specific to this version of npm.

Comment: I guess the difference is I'm not using brew, I reinstalled using npm/n. And no plans to try a global update again, hah.